# How to improve this TCP code?

Tags: c#, .net, sockets, tcpclient

There are times that the `recByte` will fail to receive response even though the server
did reply because the server wasn't fast enough. Which if happened I use

```
catch (System.IO.IOException ioe)
```

to prevent the error, but are there possible alternatives that allow the client to wait a bit longer?
I did try

```
clientStream.ReadTimeout = 20000;
```

but it didn't work

```
TcpClient Client = new TcpClient();
Client.Connect(ipaddress, portnum);

NetworkStream clientStream = Client.GetStream();

byte[] buffer = themessagetosent;
clientStream.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);

byte[] recByte = theresponse;
clientStream.Read(recByte, 0, recByte.Length);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to increase timeout for the tcpClient, not for the stream. Also, probably want to increase timeout for both `send` and `receive`, and probably to more than just 2 sec.

```
var client = new TcpClient { SendTimeout = 10000, ReceiveTimeout = 10000 };
```

I believe if you look at inner exception in IOException, you will see SocketException inside. Look at error code to find out what exactly is happening.

Comment: Increasing the ReceiveTimeOut didn't seem to help, it appears that the program didn't know how to receive a delayed message The error was System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond @AlexAza

Comment: What is the value of `SocketErrorCode`?

Comment: I assume this is happening on `clientStream.Read`, which means that either you need to wait for longer, or server is simply doesn't respond.

Comment: Your right, it appears that the server is not responding properly awhile ago Thanks @AlexAza

Answer (score 1):

If the server sends very fewer bytes, you could consider using socket.NoDelay = false at the server end (also at client side if required), this disable the Nagle algorithm and force the tcp/ip stack to send the data immediately without looking for further data to collect.

CanRead and DataAvailable are used good at when you have dedicated thread to handle the socket and data read.

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm not the one who controls the server @Gopalakrishnan

Comment: socket.NoDelay=true, disable the Nagle algorithm

Answer (score 0):

Check out the use of `CanRead` and `DataAvailable` in this [example on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.networkstream.read.aspx).

Comment: It doesn't make it to DataAvailable, it either hangs in the NetworkStream.Read or skips to the IOException Error @WillA